# How do I detect a mentioned member and assign a role to them with a discord bot? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, roles

I'm trying to set up a Discord bot that will give users a pre-made role called 'Suspended' after a command is typed by a user. I want the command to be !suspend @user length but I'm not sure how to tell if a user is mentioned.

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new Commando.Client();
const TOKEN = 'redacted'

bot.registry.registerGroup('simple', 'Simple');
bot.registry.registerDefaults();
bot.registry.registerCommandsIn(__dirname + '/commands');


bot.on('message', function(message){
    if(message.content == 'testk.1')
    {
        message.channel.sendMessage('Hi ' + message.author + ' nab.');
    }
    if(message.content == 'testk.2')
    {
        message.member.send("Nabwoo XD");
    }
    if(message.content == '!suspend', mentionsMember) //This is the part im 
having an issue on
    {
         message.channel.sendMessage('works');
    }
});
bot.on('ready',function(){
console.log("Ready");
})
bot.login(TOKEN);
```

How could I assign the role named 'Suspended' to the user that is mentioned in the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways you could handle this. Below is just one method by splitting the string into an array by spaces, and seeing if there are 3 parts and ensuring that the first part is `!suspend` and the second part starts with an `@`. Of course you could make it more rubust based on your needs.

```
    if(message.content.split(" ").length === 3 && message.content.split(" ")[0] == '!suspend' && message.content.split(" ")[1].startsWith("@"))
    {
         var mentionsMember = message.content.split(" ")[1]; // 2nd item in array when text is split by spaces, (ex. `@user`)
         message.channel.sendMessage('works');
    }
```

Comment: In

 if(message.content.split(" ").length === 3 && message.content.split(" ")[0] == '!suspend' && message.content.split(" ")[0] === "@")

I changed the last zero to a one because that's what it should be in the array right?
Also, it still sends the default unknown command whenever I type !suspend, !suspend @(any user here), or !suspend @(any user) (any message). Will the @ in the if statement need to be filled in with a specific user or will it work with any mentioned user as long as it has an @?

Comment: @Mason You are 100% correct. I'll edit the answer now. It should work with any user so long as it has an @. You need 3 elements. So you do need to use `!suspend @(any user) (any message)`.

Comment: @Mason I also realized I made one error that I just corrected in my edit.

Comment: It works whenever I type the @, but not whenever I tag someone because I think discord recognizes it another way but I think I can fix that. It works great other than the fact that for some reason it outputs the error message as well as 'works'. Hopefully this will be an easy fix. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Mason Of course! Hopefully that gets you on the right track. If it's related to an issue in my answer don't hesitate to comment if you run into further problems after testing further.

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks again!